# Troubleshooting a revert on Ropsten

Tags: etherscan, ropsten, ethereumjs

I’ve deployed a contract to Ropsten and am testing it manually with Remix. This [transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x4b387b35650fbe80b38e0c3055da10141c943fd66f8bc7ede78a61d279c71c32) reverts for whatever reason (we have unit tests where everything looks fine).

In our contract for all of our require statements we have corresponding, custom revert messages. Is there a way to see the revert message in Etherscan or elsewhere to find out why exactly this transaction is reverting?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you can't see revert messages in etherscan.io.

If you can reproduce this on ganache, ganache will provide the revert message.

Beyond that you'd have to share the code, or even better verify it on etherscan (Ropsten) if you wanted help debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the transaction in Remix
https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_debug.html

Reposting answer from: https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/t/troubleshooting-a-revert-on-ropsten/967